# looking for help in configuring .emacs file for python (python.el),

Tags: emacs, python.el

My emacs version is 24.5, using in built python. I have written these lines in my `.emacs` for it:

```
(require 'python)
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:/Python34")
```

The problem is none of the commands (when I am trying to run `test.py`) are working. I have tried several commands named like

```
M-x python-shell-*
```

and they all return

```
"wrong type argument:arrayp, nil".
```

What I am doing wrong?
What am I supposed to do?
What should be ideal configuration (`.emacs`)?

Further info:

- Python 3.4 installed at `C:/`
- Emacs at `C:/Program Files/`
- `$HOME` is `C:/user/akk/appdata/roaming/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That variable is for the Python *interpreter*, not the Python *directory*.

I don't have a Windows machine to test on, but if you update your configuration to point to the actual binary (possibly `C:/Python34/python.exe`?) you should find that it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the mode documentation in the top of python.el, you can set this on windows like (change `Python27` to `Python34` for your use case:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "C:\\Python27\\python.exe")
```